# Running scheduled DML query on Firebase analytics dataset

Tags: google-bigquery, google-workflows

I am trying to run a scheduled DML query from our Firebase analytics dataset. (Backstory, we have a lot of extra events that are no longer needed and for the time being it is easier to drop them from BigQuery).

I thought I might be able to run the query such as the following:

```sql
DELETE FROM  `my-project.analytics_1234567890.*`
    WHERE  _TABLE_SUFFIX 
    BETWEEN CONCAT('events_', format_date('%Y%m%d', date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, interval 7 day))) 
        AND CONCAT('events_', format_date('%Y%m%d', CURRENT_DATE))
     AND event_name IN ('not a real event')
```

But, BigQuery complains with this error: `DML over table my-project.analytics_1234567890.* is not supported`

Is there a way to query dynamic table names in scheduled DML queries so I can drop specific rows from the last 7 partitions?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article on how to resolve repetitive queries with scheduled invocations, combine simple queries to complex DML statements by using Cloud Workflows.

[Automate the execution of BigQuery queries with Cloud Workflows](https://martonkodok.medium.com/automate-the-execution-of-bigquery-queries-with-cloud-workflows-9fffe0557dbb)

essentially it covers your use case:

Workflow Steps for your problem

1. Run a query to get the table names
2. Loop for each table to launch a task for it
3. Execute the parameterized task for each result

**workflow.yaml**

```
#workflow entrypoint 
main:
  steps:
    - getList:
        call: BQ_Query
        args:
          query: select distinct _TABLE_SUFFIX as table_id FROM  `my-project.analytics_242990349.*`
                    WHERE  _TABLE_SUFFIX 
                    BETWEEN CONCAT('events_intraday_', format_date('%Y%m%d', date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, interval 7 day))) 
                        AND CONCAT('events_intraday_', format_date('%Y%m%d', CURRENT_DATE))
        result: items
    - loopItems:
        call: BQ_Results_LoopItems
        args:
          items: ${items.rows}
        result: res
    - final:
        return: ${res}
BQ_Query:
    params: [query]
    steps:
      - runBQquery: 
          call: googleapis.bigquery.v2.jobs.query
          args:
              projectId: ${sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID")}
              body:
                  useLegacySql: false
                  query: ${query}
          result: queryResult
      - documentFound:
          return: ${queryResult}
BQ_Results_LoopItems:
  params: [items]
  steps:
    - init:
        assign:
          - i: 0
          - result: ""
    - check_condition:
        switch:
          - condition: ${len(items) > i}
            next: iterate
        next: exit_loop
    - iterate:
        steps:
          - process_item:
              call: BQ_Task
              args:
                table_id: ${items[i].f[0].v}
              result: result
          - assign_loop:
              assign:
                - i: ${i+1}
        next: check_condition
    - exit_loop:
        return: ${result}
BQ_Task:
  params: [table_id]
  steps:
    - delete:
        call: BQ_Query
        args:
          query: ${"DELETE FROM `my-project.analytics_242990349."+table_id+"`
                    WHERE event_name IN ('not a real event')"}
        result: queryResult
    - documentFound:
        return: ${queryResult}
```